# How can I arrange my plots using subfloat?

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subfig

[image: old]

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{subfig}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{a.eps}} \qquad
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{b.eps}} \\
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:c}]{\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{c.eps}}} 
    \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
    \label{Airline}
\end{figure}
```

I used to arrange three plots in the above way, but now my plots are in different shapes and I want to arrange them in the way below. Can I do so with the least change of the LaTex code?

[image: new]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two `minipage` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering 
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{example-image-1x1}} 
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{example-image-b}}  \\
    \subfloat[\label{Airline:c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.98\textwidth]{example-image-c}} 
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
    \label{Airline}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is neat!